# Downloading file from amazon s3 in ios

Tags: ios, amazon-s3, asihttprequest

Hi guys I am having a problem downloading file from a amazon s3 url having format:

https://s3.amazonaws.com:443/[Something]/[filename].mp3?Signature=[signature]&Expires=[Expiry]&AWSAccessKeyId=[AccessID]

The above url is just a format and is confidential so I cannot post a actual URL.

I am using ASIHTTPRequest to download the file but getting http status code 403(forbidden) and response string as null.

When I paste the link in the address bar of web browser, browser plays the songs.

This is the code :

```
if (!networkQueue) {
    networkQueue = [ASINetworkQueue queue];
}
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
ASIHTTPRequest *downloadRequest = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[mediaUrlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] ]];
[downloadRequest setRequestMethod:@"GET"];    
[downloadRequest setShouldRedirect:YES];    
NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.mp3",[dict valueForKey:@"ID"]];
fileName = [fileName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",documentsDirectory,fileName];
NSLog(@"File Path: %@",filePath);

[downloadRequest setDownloadDestinationPath:filePath];
[downloadRequest setDownloadProgressDelegate:[downloadView viewWithTag:2]];
[downloadRequest setDelegate:self];
[downloadRequest setDidFinishSelector:@selector(downloadFinished:)];
[downloadRequest setDidFailSelector:@selector(downloadFailed:)];
[networkQueue addOperation:downloadRequest];
[networkQueue go];
```

Is is possible to download a file using amazon s3 url have the above format. If yes, how?
Thanks in advance for you help

Comment: So you've logged the URL you create from the debugger, pasted that URL into your browser, and it worked in the browser but not in the app?

Comment: Yes, If I open the url in browser, it plays but doesn't download in app using the above code.

Comment: Sounds like it could be a bug in ASI then what other libraries have you tried?

Comment: I don't think this as a bug because I also tried to use [NSData dataWithContentOfURL:]. But no luck.

Comment: Are you sure this actually a networking/iOS bug, and not an audio format that iOS doesn't support? I would test with something simpler first, like a text file or JPG image. The only thing I see odd about your URL is that you are specifying a port; you shouldn't need to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not a direct answer to your question, but rather than using ASIHTTPRequest - which stopped active development last year, wouldn't it be easier to just use the [AWS SDK for iOS](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforios/) which is provided by Amazon?

Comment: I don't have any credentials for amazon s3. The link is generated by a sever on request and provide it against its api call. I don't know if AWS SDK for ios will help in downloads without credentials.

Comment: I also tried to use the ASIS3ObjectRequest provided by ASIHTTPRequest. but my program gives EXEC_BAD_ACCESS when I call [asiNetworkQueue go]

Comment: Then you are better off trying to find out what is wrong with the way you're using the aws sdk rather than switching to a different framework that you can't get to work either. IMO, of course.